# Using -m during add, commit and push alias

Tags: git, github

Normally, I need to do:

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "message"
$ git push
```

to push my work to the server and view my changes. Since I need to do this for all little changes, it's a huge time kill. I currently have an alias for the git add, commit and push:

```
[alias]
    ap = !git add -A && git commit && git push
```

Is there a way to avoid VIM editor opening by setting a commit message using `-m`? I've tried doing `git ap -m "message"` but that still opens the VIM editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this is what you are looking for:

```
[alias]
ap="!f() { git add -A && git commit \"$@\" && git push; }; f"
```

Then you can run `git ap -m "blah blah blah"`, and the extra arguments get fed to the `git commit` part...

Comment: I get the errors: 
`f(){git add -A && git commit $@ && git push;}:F -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token '{git'` and 
`f(){git add -A && git commit $@ && git push;}:F -c: line 0:'f(){git add -A &&git commit $@ &&git push;}:f "$@"`

Comment: That's a semicolon before the last `f`, not a colon, and the `f` should be lower case - it's an invocation of the function defined by the rest of the line... Also, the quotes around `$@` are significant - don't leave them out.

Comment: @kaman Good point - I had a quick look at my collection of aliases, and realized the internal quotes do need to be escaped... Thanks, and updated...

Comment: @twalberg actually i just checked and apparently it works without them too:) that's why i deleted my comment

Comment: Tried both suggestions:
`ap = "!f(){git add -A && git commit \"$@" && git push;};f"` and testing it using: `$ git ap -m "testing alias"` but I still get the error `unexpected token '{git`.

Comment: @cat-t escape both quotes `\"$@\"` or don't escape at all. works either way

Comment: It appears there actually needs to be a space after the opening brace... Fixed...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to do it using the Git alias ability, but as a bash function:

```
git-ap() {
  git add .;
  git commit -am "$1";
  git push;
}
```

Then, to use it:

```
$ git-ap "This is a commit message"
```

Comment: The quotes around `$1` should be necessary, I think.

Comment: @DietrichEpp In this case yeah they probably are, since git uses argv directly.

Comment: How exactly do you go about adding functions to git?

Comment: @cat-t: In this case, instead of adding the function to git, the suggestion creates a bash function.  Put it in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`.

Comment: You can make an alias out of it easily. Just open `~/.gitconfig` in any editor and under `[alias]` (if it's not there just add the line) put `<alias name> = "!f() { git add -A; git commit -m \"$1\"; git push;}; f"` . Now you have you have same functionality but execute as if it was native git feature. Also i don't think `-a` option is necessary since with the commit since `-A` is used when adding.